# How to merge dictionary entry's value to List of string

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Field {
   public string FieldName  { get; set; }   
}

Dictionary<String, Field> rawListDict = new Dictionary<String, Field>();
```

Need linq query to create `List<string>` where - `FieldName` of `Field` class for each dictionary entry.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and what kind of problem you have with your code. Some unexpected items in list?

Comment: `new List<string>(rawListDict.Values.Select(v => v.FieldName))`

Comment: Your previous question was closed. And you still didn't read [How to Ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I have checked your other questions - they show you put zero efforts on solving your tasks

Comment: its ok to have List too. Just need linq to have list of string as fieldname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
List<string> result = rawListDict.Select(x => x.Value.FieldName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help you out.

```
List<string> rawListDict = new List<string>();
var query = rawListDict.Select(x=>x.FieldName);
```

Here `query` will have your required list of strings available in `Field` class.